# Facebook graph api limit parameter strange behaviour

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Until today I could do requests such as the following successfully

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/[PAGE_ID]/posts?access_token=[TOKEN]&since=2014-03-17T00:00:00Z&until=2014-03-17T23:59:59Z&limit=250&fields=id,message
```

Today when I tried to make this request I get the following response:

```
{
"error":{
    "message":"(#100) The 'limit' parameter should not exceed 200",
    "type":"OAuthException","code":100
}
}
```

Which is funny because the [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed?locale=en_GB) mentions that the upper bound of the `limit` parameter is 250. Am I missing something or is there something wrong with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug as been corrected as of January 30th.

[Post limit change from documented max of 250 to 200 bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1518130385135066/)

Answer (score 1):

@Potaoes I suspect this is an error related to them solving some back-end and latency issues. Discussed here. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/320942614776706/

They are currently in the middle of push ( I assume to correct this error). https://developers.facebook.com/status/dashboard/

Finally the error has been reported. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1518130385135066/

@Vineesh The OP is correct. It's against all the API documentation that the limit has been 250 since v2.0. There has been no documented change to this.

Answer (score 0):

The Error message exactly shows the Error.

The 'limit' parameter **should not exceed 200**",

You have given  limit=250,

reduce the limit then try again.

Comment: It works when I reduce the error but when I reduce it but a limit of 250 should work as per [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed?locale=en_GB) , that's my question

Comment: @potatoes: that may be in the previous versions.

Comment: No, it's v2.2 and i'm using v2.2 (look at the URL)